# command not found: if when running package.json script with Yarn v3 (berry)

Tags: yarnpkg, npm-scripts, yarnpkg-v3

I upgraded our projects yarn from v1.22 to v3.1.1. We use workspaces, so I have that plugin. Everything seems fine; other scripts work but when trying to use shell commands I get this error:

```
> yarn run start
command not found: if
command not found: then
command not found: fi
```

Here is the script from our package.json:

```json
"scripts": {
    "build": "yarn run --top-level tsc",
    "lint": "yarn run --top-level eslint './src/**/*.{ts,js}'",
    "start": "if [[ $BLAH ]]; then yarn generateEnvFile; fi && yarn copyEnterpriseWsdl && node dist/index.js",
    "generateEnvFile": "node blah.js > .env",
    "copyEnterpriseWsdl": "cp blah blah"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with more of a workaround than figuring out what the issue was:

```json
"scripts": {
    // ...
    "start": "/bin/sh ./start-prod.sh"
  }
```

Where that script has what I really need to run. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to keep the code inline, you can use the following:

```json
"scripts": {
    // ...
    "start": "/bin/sh -c 'if [[ $BLAH ]]; then yarn generateEnvFile; fi' && yarn copyEnterpriseWsdl && node dist/index.js"
  }
```